# Searching for attributes

Tags: xml, database, search, clusterpoint, nosql

I have the following database in Clusterpoint:

```
<db>
  <document>
    <id>1</id>
    <name lang="en">John</name>
    <name lang="ru">Джон</name>
  </document>
  <document>
    <id>2</id>
    <name lang="en">Bill</name>
    <name lang="ru">Билл</name>
  </document>
</db>
```

I am willing to perform a query searching for a specific name. Normally I would specify:

```
<query><name>Bill</name></query>
```

However this might match both English and Russian name.

How can I make sure that search would only look inside name with attribute `lang="en"`?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define attributes as **child tags** in request and use them in search, aggregation, ordering etc.

If you want to search for the <name> with certain attribute value, then just specify it in query:

```
<query><name>Bill<lang>en</lang></name></query>
```

This will search for documents where both conditions are matched. So, if your database contains, for example, documents (I've added document with id=3):

```
<db>
  <document>
    <id>1</id>
    <name lang="en">John</name>
    <name lang="ru">Джон</name>
  </document>
  <document>
    <id>2</id>
    <name lang="en">Bill</name>
    <name lang="ru">Билл</name>
  </document>
  <document>
    <id>3</id>
    <name lang="it">Bill</name>
    <name lang="ru">Билл</name>
  </document>
</db>
```

then query mentioned above (with defined attributes) will return document with id=2.

But if you will search by:

```
<query><name>Bill</name></query>
```

then you will get two documents with id=2 and id=3.

Be carefull, if there are repetitive tags, than it is necessary to use tag colocation by defining rule "colocate=yes" in policy configuration for appropriate tag (in your case - <name>), and by using "@" operator in query.

If you add document to your database:

```
<document>
    <id>4</id>
    <name lang="en">Steve</name>
    <name lang="ru">John</name>
</document>
```

And will try to return documents, where both conditions match values inside one repetitive tag, then query:

```
<query><name>John<lang>en</lang></name></query>
```

will return incorrect result - documents with id=1 and id=4.

But by defining "colocate=yes" for <name> and using "@" operator:

```
<query> @ <name>John<lang>en</lang></name> @ </query>
```

you will get correct one - with id=1.

Comment: This does not work. Add one more document with <name lang="en">Steve</name> and <name lang="ru">John</name>. If you will do search on <query><name>John<lang>en</lang></name></query> you will get first doc and the one that I suggested even though lang for my John is "ru".

Comment: @Endijs
You are right, if there are repetitive tags in one document, this will not work, because this query searches for matches in all document tags separately, not in "linked" tags.
For this purpose you should use "tag colocation" function. I've just added this example in answer (thank you for this reference).

Comment: Ah. I also tried ' @ ' approach and it did not work before. Now after adding appropriate Policy rule it started to work. :)